# How to type ろ in Japanese kana mode on US-English keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, language, japanese, macos

I tried the Japanese kana input method (prior to that I used romaji method) but it seems designed for Japanese hardware keyboard, which has one more key on the next to the right-shift key.

However on the US-English, there is no such redundant hardware key, making it impossible to type in ろ character.

So is there any way to type in ろ in US-English keyboard on macOS?

Comment: Is Unicode hex-input an option?

Comment: It’s not impossible to type ろ -- this characater is just located at a different place on the US (ANSI) keyboard than on the Japanese (JIS) keyboard,  on the shift level and one row higher up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Japanese Hiragana Input Source, with the preference for Typing Method set to "Kana", you should find ろ at Shift plus け (the key marked ' on the US keyboard), next to the return key, as shown below:

[image]

[Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25242) is useful for solving such problems.

Comment: maybe you care to explain how you got there

Comment: How to type the "Shift plus"? Typing with Shitf key does not change anything.

Comment: @Blaszard　You don't type "plus", just Shift apostrophe ('). Do you not get ろ?  Do you get け instead?

Comment: @Blaszard Doesn't the shift key produce the punctuation marks on the right end of the bottom row for you --  、。・　-- instead of  ねるめ?

Comment: @TomGewecke Ah I found I used Karabiner-Element to remap the keys, which makes it incompatible with your solution. But yours is the correct answer, thanks.